# Como saber quantos Bytes tem arquivo através do ArrayBuffer do Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com uma aplicação de upload de arquivos, e preciso saber como identificar quantos bytes tem meu arquivo, é por isso que estou utilizando Arraybuffer, eu sei que existe outras maneiras que medir o tamanho do arquivo, mas eu gostaria mesmo de utilizar o Arraybuffer, essa foi minha tentativa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não sei se estou fazendo da forma certa, e a forma correta seria outra, eu preciso saber a forma correta e aceito sugestões, aqui está o trecho do código.

```
if (x != "undefined"){//uint8array, arraybuffer
                await jsZipInstance.file(x).async("arraybuffer").then(function (data) {
                    var view = new Int8Array(data);
                    console.log(view.length);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/length

Comment: Leia os documento explica com exemplos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array